# Do search results change based on reputation?

Tags: support, tags, search

I've noticed that on some sites (say [Christianity.SE](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/)) when I search for a word that happens to be a tag, it helpfully converts that term into a search for a particular tag.  (A search for `bible` becomes `[bible]`.  If I want to search the *text* of the posts, I must use `+bible` or `"bible"`.)

On the other hand, on a site where I have relatively high reputation ([Hermeneutics.SE](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/)) the search does not convert.

I do have a higher reputation on SO (thanks to the [power law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_law)), but my search terms *do* convert there.  I guess that it's comparing apples to kumquats since SO has graduated from beta and the other sites I checked haven't.  During the beta period, user privileges are granted at [lower reputation thresholds](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared).

So is my hypothesis correct?  Do search terms convert to tag searches below some reputation threshold?  Is this documented somewhere?

---

Secondly, does this cause any (real) problems?  I realized that if I tell a new user to search for something that happens to be a tag, they will get fewer results than I do.  Even if I share a link such as `https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/search?q=mark`, it will be converted to `https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mark` when a new user tries it.  My instinct is to say that's a UI and social nightmare.  But maybe there are good reasons for this...

(By the way, if I really want to make a link that will work for everyone, I think I should use this form: `https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2Bmark` or `https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22mark%22`.)

Comment: You could always log out and check for yourself. You don't need an account to search.

Comment: Of course, I found the answer in comment to a Related [question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97056/1438) _after_ posting this question.  Oh well: this one is for posterity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually it looks like [the magic works](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/stack-overflow-search-now-61-less-crappy/) a bit differently than I had guessed:

> Any individual search terms which map directly to the top 40 tags will be **auto-converted to tag searches**. So if you enter
> c++ entities

> it will convert to

> [c++] entities

> automagically on your behalf.

It seems the new user would get the same results as anyone else who searches at the same point in time.