# Add search option for tag info

Tags: discussion

Add search option, for example

```
`info: html` or `define:html`
```

to open the tag info page (as example for [html](/questions/tagged/html) -> https://stackoverflow.com/tags/html/info)

Comment: When we are on any tag's page e.g. [`html`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) then clicking on *info* will redirect you to the info tab.

Comment: Know that, but I think it would be nice if we can just type define:html, and get tag(info) page.

Comment: Ok, guys got it! Just like google have define: I thought it would be nice to have it here.

Answer (score 3):

If you search for something that *is a tag* (caveat: I can't remember if there is some restriction there, i.e. some nominal level of usage), then the search automatically takes you to the "tagged" page, i.e. searching on `html` takes you to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html; which means the tag wiki's excerpt is displayed *immediately*, and the full info is only one click away:

[image]

Comment: **Nominal level of usage** ... Looking for [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97104/166025) and [this](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/stack-overflow-search-now-61-less-crappy/)?

Comment: @AzizShaikh well, yes and no; things can change since 2011 (the first) and 2009 (the second) ;p